# Inconsistent and incorrect results when running my code in parallel with different numbers of threads

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a Fortran code that utilizes OpenMP. When I run the code without OpenMP or with OpenMP and with 9 threads, I obtain correct results. The code essentially consists of a single subroutine called within a parallelized do loop for 9 input values. This subroutine contains multiple nested subroutines.

However, when I run the code with any other number of threads, the results become incorrect and peculiar. The code takes 9 pairs of input values, where 5 pairs are distinct: (0.4, -0.3), (0.5, -0.45), (0.55, -0.3), (0.6, -0.45), and (0.66, -0.43). For each pair, the code computes a time series. The attached image displays [(Results)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xttyo.jpg) the correct time series (top figure) obtained using 9 threads (I replicated the values to verify that different threads yield identical results).

In the case of running the code with 5 threads, the time series from each thread appear very similar, except for a sudden jump in values towards the end. The results are presented in the bottom of the attached image [(Results)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xttyo.jpg)

I have attempted various approaches to address this issue. These include inserting !$OMP BARRIER at multiple sections of the code, utilizing !$OMP CRITICAL, modifying variables within shared, private, and first private directives, adjusting ulimit -s to unlimited, increasing OMP_STACKSIZE, trying different optimizations, and more. Despite these efforts, the results remain incorrect.

I need to run this code for 14k input values but need the code to calculate the time series appropriately for this 9 (5) values.

I understand it is challenging to provide specific advice without examining the actual code, however I am unable to share it here due to restrictions on rights.

Thank you in advance for any assistance or suggestions!

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask] and especially [mcve]. It is very important to show the code. Even if your production code is secret, you should be able to create a minimal verifiable example.

Comment: It's not challenging, it's nearly impossible...